# qtdbus under windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, qt

**CONFIGURATION**
I have this configuration:

1. QT Community 5.4.1
2. dbus-daemon.exe downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/windbus/ 
   link
3. I have copied in my local directory these qt example:
   c:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Examples\Qt-5.4\dbus\remotecontrolledcar\car
   c:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Examples\Qt-5.4\dbus\remotecontrolledcar\controller
4. I use Windows 7 and NOT Linux!!!!!!

**Procedure:**

1. I compiled both examples in debug mode in my local directory
2. I launched dbus-daemon.exe with these parameters:
   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS sets to tcp; host sets to localhost,port sets to 12434.
   set DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_DEFAULT_ADDRESS=tcp:host=localhost,port=12434
   dbus-daemon.exe --session --system --config-file=.\etc\session.conf
3. I execute car.exe
4. I execute controller.exe

**PROBLEM**
The dbus connection fails in particular the method sessionBus  form DBusConnection class fails. Infact when i call the isConnected method, it returns false.

Someone can explain why? Is it wrong the way I call the daemon executable?
Or Qt Comunity 5.4.1 have problem with qtdbus? can someone pass me a correct configuration file (session.conf)?

Thank you very much for for the support.
Fausto

Comment: Did you set the session bus or the system bus variables? Your question seems a bit mixed.

Comment: I found this workaround: I installed DBus-Windows-Installer-1.4.1-2.exe. Second: i run dbus-daemon.exe. Third, i run the application qdbus.exe. Finally i run car.exe and controller.exe. The controller.exe drives car.exe correctly.